# Motorcycle LiFePO 4 / Super capacitor 24v hybrid possibilities?

Tags: lithium-ion

First please let me apologise, I’m quite frankly a complete newbie to electronics and come from a strictly design background. However, I'm really interested in learning and understanding electronics and especially incorporating new tech in ways that haven’t been done before. (Well I can try!!)

One of my motorcycles, an extensively modified Suzuki hyabusa requires a 24v feed to the starter due to the high compression of the engine and at the moment the bike has 2 heavy lead acid batteries powering it. One under the seat and one sitting on top of the engine. Not only are these heavy but they are inconvenient as the second batt is wired in after the starter relay and discharges after about 6 starts, requiring me to lift the tank and connect a charger after every ride. This has always bugged me.

Now I have an idea...

A DIY LiFePO battery which would work in a traditional way controlling the standard 12v feeds for the bike and some form of ultra-capacitor wired in series that would deliver a short powerful 12v boost that would be connected in series to the starter. Almost as if there was 2 separate batteries in one battery box. I’d like to keep the whole package as small and lightweight as possible yet deliver enough punch to start even on the warmest of days

Are ultra-capacitors the right way, or should I scrap that idea and use another bank of LiFePO to give me the boost?

I’d also like to include a form of charging circuit into the package along with the correct balance chargers and protection circuits to stop overcharging etc.

Any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be amazing, I understand I will know a lot less than 99% of people on here.. But please don’t shoot me down.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ultracapacitors are regularly between 2.7V and 3V meaning you need to put several in series. As soon as you put several in series you need a way to make sure they stay sort of balanced. Minor things can cause them to charge or deplete more rapidly then the others and things can go bad. Also wise to think of overcharging protection.

Comment: First, why not just check out “split charge” systems - there are relays built that will charge your second battery once the engine is running. This may be an easier solution. Those relays are used by people with caravans, with winches etc anyone with a second battery.

Comment: I already have one of those, I'm just looking to create a more efficiant solution that is lighter and more powerful than using 2 seperate wet batteries. I see no reason why 2 lithium based circuits cant fit into a wet battery sized container and potentially have twice the cranking power of the current setup

Comment: @WD1 you do not say you have a split-charge relay / system,but you do point out that you have to charge your second battery after about 6 starts -which implies that there is no charging to the second battery...